# Controlling for Type 1 Errors: Post-hoc testing on more than 1 ANOVA

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni, tukey-hsd-test, type-i-and-ii-errors

I have conducted several repeated-measures ANOVA's with post-hoc testing via Tukey's HSD whenever the omnibus F-test was significant. I'm having some confusion about controlling for type 1 errors when presenting these post hoc tests.

Q1: It's my understanding that Tukey's HSD will control the Type-1 error rate only for the set of post-hoc comparisons coming from one ANOVA. Is this correct? If so, do I need to take additional precautions to limit Type-1 errors with post-hoc comparisons from more than one ANOVA?

Q2: If I do need to take further action, what should I do? Suppose I have 2 ANOVA's with 6 post-hoc comparisons each. If I did a Bonferonni correction, would I use the number of post-hoc tests (so, 12) or the number of ANOVA's (2), and would I still use Tukey's HSD at all? Is there a completely different approach/control I should consider?